# The conversation between D'anconia and Reardon

Tags: ayn-rand, atlas-shrugged

I'm listening to Atlas Shrugged on audiobook and one of the discs was messed up.  At the point D'anconia told Reardon he had always loved a woman and it was after his trial, the disc died.  The next disc has Dagny asking R D'anconia what he did to Reardon because he said he could murder him. What did they talk about?  Did he tell him he loved Dagny?

Answer (score 3):

Hank Reardon had secretly ordered copper from d'Anconia Copper so that he could produce more Reardon Metal (in spite of d'Anconia's request that he have no business dealings with d'Anconia Copper). When d'Anconia found out about the order, he had Ragnar Danneskjold sink the ship that was supposed to be delivering the copper so that it would not reach Hank Reardon. When Hank found out, he was so enraged by the act that "...he thought that he must now keep away from the Wayne-Falkland or he would kill Francisco d'Anconia on sight."